# App not opening selecting item and crashing at `onShowFileChooser`

Tags: android

Trying to load my html in webview, it is very simple that have a file open button:

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
```

I was able to make wbview setup, and load this file, and understood that upon clicking it, I've to override the `onShowFileChooser` function, so I wrote the below, but my up is crashing upon clicking the html element:

```kotlin
package tk.anative

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        Global.webView = binding.webView
        WebListener.initiate()
        Global.webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onShowFileChooser(
                webView: WebView,
                filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>,
                fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams
            ): Boolean {

                Toast.makeText(Global.context, "Hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null)
                return true
            }
        } 
        WebSettings.setUp()
    }
}
```

If I removed the:

```
Toast.makeText(Global.context, "Hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
```

Then the app is not crashing, but if I tried to execute anything there I get it crashed.

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: @CommonsWare I updated my question, and added it. thanks

Comment: That is all from the system Dialer app, not yours.

Comment: @CommonsWare then I do not get any error there